# what is the difference between those two assertions?

Tags: system-verilog-assertions

let' say I have two properties;

```
property p1;
sig_a ##1 sig_b;
endproperty

property p2;
sig_a |=> sig_b;
endproperty
```

now if i do assertion like this:

```
a1: assert property (p1);
a2: assert property (p2);
```

Does a1 and a2 make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between system_verilog `property` and `sequence` syntax.
`property p1` doesn't have triggering condition. In other words , it will always being checked on clocking event. It just mentions sequence of operation to be checked. i.e. `sequence` in sv assertion. You could assume `property p1` in below manner.

```
property p1;
  1'b1 |-> sig_a ##1 sig_b;
endproperty
```

It will always fail , if sig_a is zero-value.

Now `property p2` is having triggering condition which is sig_a == non_zero value. if this condition is true then it will evaluate sig_b value after 1 clocking event.